# Python: POST request to API failed

Tags: python, api, python-requests, http-post, parameter-passing

I am trying to send a POST request to [Walmart API](https://developer.walmart.com/api/us/mp/onrequestreports#operation/generateReport) to request reports. But it is returning me 'Report request failed.' message with json. What am I doing wrong? I don't really have that much experience with API calls in python. Here is my code.

I have a class called "Walmart" to interact with the Walmart Marketplace API. It has methods to authenticate with the API, send requests and handle responses.

```
class Walmart(object):

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret):
        """To get client_id and client_secret for your Walmart Marketplace
        visit: https://developer.walmart.com/#/generateKey
        """
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.token = None
        self.token_expires_in = None
        self.base_url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3"

        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers.update({
            "WM_SVC.NAME": "Walmart Marketplace",
            "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID": uuid.uuid4().hex,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        })
        session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self.client_id, self.client_secret)
        self.session = session

        # Get the token required for API requests
        self.authenticate()

    def authenticate(self):
        data = self.send_request(
            "POST", "{}/token".format(self.base_url),
            body={
                "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            },
        )
        self.token = data["access_token"]
        self.token_expires_in = data["expires_in"]

        self.session.headers["WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN"] = self.token

    @property
    def report(self):
        return Report(connection=self)

    def send_request(
        self, method, url, params=None, body=None, json=None,
        request_headers=None
    ):
        # A unique ID which identifies each API call and used to track
        # and debug issues; use a random generated GUID for this ID
        headers = {
            "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID": uuid.uuid4().hex,
            "WM_SVC.NAME": "Walmart Marketplace",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
        if request_headers:
            headers.update(request_headers)

        response = None
        if method == "GET":
            response = self.session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
        elif method == "PUT":
            response = self.session.put(
                url, params=params, headers=headers, data=body
            )
        elif method == "POST":
            request_params = {
                "params": params,
                "headers": headers,
            }
            if json is not None:
                request_params["json"] = json
            else:
                request_params["data"] = body
            response = self.session.post(url, **request_params)

        if response is not None:
            try:
                response.raise_for_status()
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                if response.status_code == 401:
                    raise WalmartAuthenticationError((
                        "Invalid client_id or client_secret. Please verify "
                        "your credentials from https://developer.walmart."
                        "com/#/generateKey"
                    ))
                elif response.status_code == 400:
                    data = response.json()
                    if "error" in data and data["error"][0]["code"] == \
                            "INVALID_TOKEN.GMP_GATEWAY_API":
                        # Refresh the token as the current token has expired
                        self.authenticate()
                        return self.send_request(
                            method, url, params, body, request_headers
                        )
                raise
        try:
            return response.json()
        except ValueError:
            # In case of reports, there is no JSON response, so return the
            # content instead which contains the actual report
            return response.content
```

And here goes authentication and the request itself. I think I am doing it wrong with the send_request method, should I do it in a different way?

```
api_key = '<key>'
api_secret='<secret>'
wm = Walmart(api_key, api_secret)
wm.authenticate()

url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/reports/reportRequests"
headers = {
      "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID": uuid.uuid4().hex,
       "WM_SVC.NAME": "Walmart Marketplace",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Accept": "application/json",
}
data= {
        "reportType": "ITEM_PERFORMANCE",
        "reportVersion": "v1",
}
method="POST"

response_dict = wm.send_request(method, url, request_headers=headers, params=data)


if 'status_code' in response_dict and response_dict['status_code'] == 200:
    response_json = response_dict.get('json')
    request_id = response_json.get('requestId')
    print(f'Report request submitted. Request ID: {request_id}')
else:
    print('Report request failed.')
    if 'json' in response_dict:
        print(response_dict['json'])
    else:
        print(response_dict)
```

The response that I got was in the following form.

> Report request failed.
> {'requestId': '46a864e8-80e8-4019-86f0-d7a1575349a4', 'requestStatus': 'RECEIVED', 'requestSubmissionDate': '2023-02-15T18:55:03Z', 'reportType': 'ITEM_PERFORMANCE', 'reportVersion': 'v1'}

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post the response? Maybe, there's information there that could lead to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you get seems to be a successful response, as the property `requestStatus` is `RECEIVED`, and not `ERROR` (which is a possible value according to the API docs you linked).

So, the issue is probably with your response checks.

Based on your checks for response:

```py
if 'status_code' in response_dict and response_dict['status_code'] == 200:
    response_json = response_dict.get('json')
    request_id = response_json.get('requestId')
    print(f'Report request submitted. Request ID: {request_id}')
else:
    print('Report request failed.')
    if 'json' in response_dict:
        print(response_dict['json'])
    else:
        print(response_dict)
```

either `'status_code' in response_dict` or `response_dict['status_code'] == 200` is false, what makes the `else` block to be executed. I recommend you to `print(response_dict)` before the `if-else` block, to see the whole content and see which of those 2 conditions is false and handle it accordingly.

I think that the issue is that the object you get from `wm.send_request()` does not contain `status_code`, since you get the content of the response (when you `return response.json()`) and not the `session.Response` object from the `requests` lib ([see the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json)).

UPDATE:

To fix your code, you need to check the response content, which is what the `send_request()` method returns. Also note that `send_request()` already does a lot of request/response error checking and raises exceptions if necessary

```py
api_key = '<key>'
api_secret='<secret>'
wm = Walmart(api_key, api_secret)
wm.authenticate()

url = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/reports/reportRequests"
headers = {
      "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID": uuid.uuid4().hex,
       "WM_SVC.NAME": "Walmart Marketplace",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Accept": "application/json",
}
data= {
        "reportType": "ITEM_PERFORMANCE",
        "reportVersion": "v1",
}
method="POST"

# send_request() already checks for request/response errors and
# raises exceptions if they happen, so we don't need to check for
# them here. Unless we want to gracefully handle errors
response_dict = wm.send_request(method, url, request_headers=headers, params=data)

# Check if there is response and requestStatus value is not ERROR
if response_dict and response_dict.get('requestStatus') != 'ERROR':
    request_id = response_dict.get('requestId')
    print(f'Report request submitted. Request ID: {request_id}')
else:
    print('Report request failed.')
    print(response_dict)
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is in the send_request() method..  I put `print(response_dict)` before `if-else` block as you recommended, it returned 
`{'requestId': 'ad7fabd0-920e-4b6b-b667-da99a2800da0', 'requestStatus': 'RECEIVED', 'requestSubmissionDate': '2023-02-20T17:56:32Z', 'reportType': 'ITEM_PERFORMANCE', 'reportVersion': 'v1'}
Report request failed.`

How should I rewrite my method in order to check for status?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print the response to see his contents, and there may be some additional info that will help you to fix your code. Also, you can try to debug your code line by line using this https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/